# easeInBounce doesn't work correctly

Tags: jquery

I've got a slidedown function which slides a text when the page is loaded so it works correctly. But when I try to edit the transition effect it ignore me...

I'have added this js links:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And the effect I would do is easiInBounce

Here I have the code that works excepting the ease effect

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $().ready(function () {
                $(".exclass").slideDown({easeInBounce:($())}, "1000");

            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<p class="exclass">This is sliding text example! This is sliding text example!
    This is sliding text example! This is sliding text example!
    This is sliding text example! This is sliding text example! This is sliding text example!
    This is sliding text example!</p>
```

And I try to put easing: 'easeInBounce' but it doesn't work...

Here I've got a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ga6dud0m/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin you may find interesting for this job:

[jQuery Easing Plugin](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

Comment: I have only to add the js files?

Comment: It says that easeInBounce is not defined